# How to make an eye shape SVG without using path?

Tags: html, svg

I'm attempting to draw an eye shape similar to [this](https://codepen.io/samc36/pen/KNEOpG) with an SVG, and can't quite seem to get sharp enough edges. Is there an easy way to do this without having to use `<path>`?

```html
<svg width="720" height="200">
  <rect x="20" rx="80" y="20" width=100 height=150 stroke="black" stroke-width="6" style="fill-opacity: 0"></rect>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `<circle>` instead of `<rect>`.

```css
svg {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-linecap: round;
  transform-origin: center;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 10px;
}
.circle1 {
  stroke-dasharray: 360;
  stroke-dashoffset: 360;
  transform: rotate(-40deg);
}
.circle2 {
  stroke-dasharray: 360;
  stroke-dashoffset: 360;
  transform: rotate(140deg);
}
.circle3 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: lightblue;
  stroke: none;
}
.circle4 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  fill: black;
}
.circle5 {
  stroke-dasharray: 0;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke: none;
  fill: white;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <circle class="circle3" r="30" cx="100" cy="50"></circle>
  <circle class="circle1" r="80" cx="100" cy="100"></circle>
  <circle class="circle2" r="80" cx="37" cy="176"></circle>
  <circle class="circle4" r="10" cx="100" cy="50"></circle>
  <circle class="circle5" r="6" cx="108" cy="42"></circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you @thingEvery, this is a very nice solution! But how do you control the size of it? It seems like you fixed it to 200px. But what if I want it fixed, just on a different value? say 40px?